# Show desktop notification from one windows app (WPF) to another using webservice call

Tags: wpf, wcf, push-notification

I have created WPF app and installed in two different PC. now I want that when I click one button from app in 1st PC, then I should get desktop notification in 2nd PC.

So I don't know how it will be done. Whether I have to use WCF or not or anything else? If I've installed this app in multiple PC then how should I send notification to particular?

I've tried to use signalR but I didn't understand how to invoke windows form method.

The application will not be closed. it'll just minimized in the tray. so my idea is that we can invoke App method from using WCF and show notification.

I want this kind of notification for my app but from webservice:

[image: I want this kind of notification for my app but from webservice]

Answer (score 1):

You can use self hosted WCF like here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx
Use net tcp binding, it will not require administrative rights.

Also there is a need to maintain a list of addresses/hosts of the PCs where your app runs. Then according to some logic you have there, choose the one that should show your notification.
You can also use a central app that coordinates, it may be a web app. Then signalR can be helpful. It becomes like a standard chat app... google can find you plenty of implementations for that.